# Вместо того чтобы вывести число умноженное на курс доллара выводит текст сообщения умноженный на курс доллара(75 раз перевести доллары)

Tags: python, telegram, telebot, pycharm

делаю телеграм бота для перевода некоторого количества валюты в рубли
ранее все переменные были объявлены, а курс доллара получен, как сделать чтобы вместо вывода фразы перевести доллары умноженную на курс доллара, умножалось число которое я введу после фразы?

```
if message.text == "перевести доллары":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Введи сколько")
        user_chis = message.text
        dlar = dollar[0].text
        dlar = int(float(dlar.replace(",", ".")))
        perev = dlar * user_chis
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, perev)
```

Answer (score 3):

Работа с типами данных. Если у вас повторяется строка столько раз сколько стоит множитель значит вы умножаете строку на число.

Непонятно здесь:

```py
dlar = int(float(dlar.replace(",", ".")))
```

Вам нужен `int` или `float`

```py
dlar = float(dlar.replace(",", "."))
```

И далее `user_chis` переменная должна быть числом, например целым:

```py
user_chis = int(message.text) # как это будет работать зависит от данных, которые сюда прилетают в message.text
```

Теперь должно сработать и это:

```py
perev = dlar * user_chis
```